# string manipulation in Dart / flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am parsing an RSS feed that 
returns has the title in this format:

```
<title>Some Data with spaces  / Bahnofstrasse 22</title>
```

so the first thing I did is to replace the spaces with a +

```
String result = _items[index].title.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"), "+");
```

however, what I need to do is to select only the text after the / so in this case Bahnofstrasse 22, remove the spaces and add a city (e.g. Zurich) before the address so the desired results would be

Zürich,Bahnofstrasse,22

so essentially select all text after /, add Zurich and replace spaces with ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the data will always be separated by a `/`, you could look at the second element of the split. For example,

```
final result = "Zürich," + 
  _items[index].title
    .split("/")[1]
    .replaceFirst("<", "")
    .trim()
    .replaceAll(" ", ",");
```

Regular expressions would only really be useful if, for example, the format of the data were variable.

Comment: thanks a lot !! quick question does the first part   .replaceFirst("<", "") replaces the first part before / with Zürich ?

Comment: The `split("/")` splits the string before `Bahnofstrasse` and before `title>`. The `replaceFirst("<", "")`, then, removes the `<` from just before the split at `</title>`. (I've updated the answer so that it adds the `Zürich` too.)